# How to draw background image of listfield rows?

Tags: blackberry, layout, listfield

I have a customized ListField with an icon and text on each rows. How can i add background images to rows (in `drawListRow()` method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be smth like this:

```
public void drawListRow(ListField listField, 
        Graphics graphics, int index, int y, int width) {

    Bitmap bg = <here is the code to get your Bitmap for bg>;
    // probably load that bitmap once in ListField constructor 
    // to speed up the drawListRow()

    graphics.drawBitmap(0, y, bg.getWidth(), bg.getHeight(), bg, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I thought that if i draw second image (background image), it blocks first one. But if background image is drawn first, there won't be any problem. I will try now...